# IntelliJ IDEA Gradle sync

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I got gradle project, spring boot application written in java. It uses some pretty old gradle version 1.12 since it has some epic legacy configuration.

But everything was working properly, builds, reimports, syncs for gradle until I updated my IntelliJ IDEA on November 27th 2017 to a version 173.3727.127

Since then I cant do gradle sync, and I keep getting

```
Could not determine the class-path for interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModel.
```

I do not have kotlin ANYWHERE in my code, so I suspect this to be only related to upgrade of IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: Maybe an IDEA bug? I'd report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I've submitted issue here, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183166?query=org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModel
 let's see what they have to say...

Comment: I have the same issue as well with a similar configuration of gradle and java. Did you have any success or update?

Comment: @jrsall92 You can follow on this link official issue ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-183166%3Fquery%3Dorg.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModel , some say that when you disable Kotlin plugin it resolves issue but it is not helping me.